# Windows 7 login automically puts "IIIII....." in password, so it is impossible for me to login?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have no idea why this is happening.  I have ran multiple malware programs, I have run anti-virus programs, I even restored to an early point in time.  The keyboard letter "I" doesn't appear to be stuck, I am using an external keyboard by the way.  When I reboot the computer and get to the login screen, when I press ctrl-alt-del to login, it the password textbox starts putting "IIIIIIIIIIII......", it only stops when I bang on the keyboard.  I also noticed at one point that my caps lock on turned caps off and caps lock off turned caps on and some other weird behavior.  I have tried search online for similar issues, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard? This sounds pretty straight forward: the keyboard is defective.

Comment: @Moses, It starts to work when I hit the laptop keyboard, not the external one.

Comment: Laptop keyboards can go defective too. Have you tried removing the key and cleaning underneath it with some canned air? Debris can cause it to stick. Otherwise, replacing it is in order.

Answer (score 3):

One or the other of your keyboards is screwed up, whether or not "it appears to be." Not all problems are visually obvious. If you are using an external because your internal does not work right, and the internal is the one that makes some difference in the `lllll...` when you bang on it, that's a clue.

If caps lock on turns caps off, a shift key is stuck (or the keyboard is broken so that it THINKS a shift key is stuck.) That's how shift affects things when Caps Lock is on.

If your computer will boot with it disconnected, you might try disconnecting the internal keyboard. You might also try disconnecting the external keyboard, an/or using a different one. One of them is not right (reported symptoms point mostly at the internal, but it could be both feeding different parts of the problem, of course)

A liquid spill into the keyboard (even a liquid spill a long time ago) could cause all of these symptoms.